# Static Analysis of a Diagram

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-kinematics, equilibrium, statics

[image]

It is very clear $M_A$ can not be zeros under general loading conditions, so this structure must be able to rotate about A.

but the geometrical constraints will not allow it to undergo this rotatory motion.

(let's assume the structure rotates anticlockwise about A.)

It is because A is a pin joint and AB and AC should follow the arc of radius AB and AC respectively. This creates an issue because the lengths of links are constant and if they rotate there will be some extension(assuming roller is also a link) which should not be possible under rigid body assumptions.

[image]

where have I gone wrong?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a more detailed description of the problem. What are the black links connecting to the structure at $B$ and $C$? If they are elastic, pivoting around $A$ surely is possible.

Comment: @noah, they are double roller supports. i don't think they are elastic they can just as well be redundant?

Comment: If they cannot deform, you are right that this structure will not pivot about $A$.

Comment: @noah even if $M_A$ is not zero under general loading conditions? why is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that this structure cannot pivot about $A$ because of the constraints of the supports. In order to pivot, the connections to the roller supports at $B$ and $C$ would have to stretch or compress. So at the supports, the moment around $A$ is converted to a force perpendicular to the support.

This is counterintuitive, because the direction of the force at the rolling supports cannot provide a moment to counter the rotation about $A$. Here it comes down to the stiffness of the structure. If everything is ideal (no friction etc.) and the structure is perfectly rigid, it will only rotate infinitesimally to provide a lever, on which the (arbitrarily large) forces $B \rightarrow A$ and $C \rightarrow A$ can act as a counter-moment.

In a more realistic setting, it will rotate and (elastically) deform until the product of the lever and the force exerted by the deformed structure/support rods is large enough to counter the moment around $A$.

Comment: In the last para "lever" = moment arm?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's the same thing.